# Using the next() and nextInt() methods

Tags: java

I'm building a graph that lists ranking, name, an old statistic, a new statistic, and the change in them ( in that order). I have so far used the code

```
for (int rank = 0; rank < 5; rank++) {
    String name = scnr.next();
    int pop16 = scnr.nextInt();
    int pop11 = scnr.nextInt();
    canada.add(new Jurisdiction (name, pop16, pop11));
    System.out.printf(format1, rank+1, canada.get(rank).getName(), canada.get(rank).getPop16(), canada.get(rank).getPop16(), canada.get(rank).calculateChange());
}
```

to find the first 5 instances however when it tries to read a name with more than one word for example "West End" or "New England" it stops. I'm trying to figure out just exactly how I can get past this issue using different variations of the `next()` method or if theres something else I can do to solve my problem.

AND before you ask the text file im using is formatted specifically so it goes

```
stringName   intOldStat   intNewStat
```

so using `nextLine()` isnt really an option.

I need 13 instances of the different names and stats for reference.

Comment: Please show us an example input file.

Comment: Use `scnr.nextLine()` instead of `scnr.next()` because `scnr.next()` will read only `West` from `West End`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash - He already said he can't ... but we need to see some example lines to understand why.

Comment: Why is this duplicate linked? It does not really represent the question. @ArvindKumarAvinash

Comment: Are all values from different categories/columns (`stringName   intOldStat   intNewStat`) always separated by 3 spaces? Are those 3 spaces only between those categories or can they appear inside `stringName`?

Comment: @Pshemo Where did the 3 spaces come from? When looking at the edit, didn't you add those?

Comment: @maloomeister I added code formatting to example from OP's original post (without it all continues spaces ware printed as one space by browser).

Comment: `Scanner` is a terrible API that looks simple but using it is never simple. Just avoid it. Use `BufferedReader` and `readLine` and then methods like `String.split()` to split the line into the desired parts.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so your input file syntax is ... unfortunate ... because there no obvious way to know when the `stringName` finishes and the `intOldStat` starts.  If have the option, the best solution is (IMO) to change the file syntax; e.g. to use a field delimiter other than a space ... which is ambiguous.

(And it is worse that you think.  There are genuine recognized placenames that have numbers in their names; e.g. ["Town of 1770")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeen_Seventy,_Queensland).)

So how to deal with this?  Here are some ideas:

- Use `Scanner.hasInt()` and a loop and consume / reassemble the words of a place name until you get a number.  (But the fails for 1770!)
- Read a complete line and then use `String.split` to split into words.  Then treat the last two words in the array as the "stat" values and turn them into numbers using `Integer.parseInt`.
- Read a complete line and parse it using a `regex` with groups to match the 3 components.

Or go crazy and write a parser ...